# Excel Change value of each cell with a value in row to count+1 of cells with values in row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have the following spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet]

I have 57 rows and ~750 columns, in some cells I will have the number one. I want to change the cells with one to a rolling count for each row. I have shown what I want to achieve below:

[image: How I want spreadsheet]

Is there some formula I can apply to achieve this result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find and Replace**

Find what: `1`

Replace with: `=COUNT(INDIRECT("RC1:RC[-1]",FALSE))+1`

Match entire cell contents

[image]

The `INDIRECT()` function lets you define a range with text. I'm using here only because it lets use write a formula in R1C1 format instead of A1 format. `RC1:RC[-1]` equates to `every cell on this row from column 1 to the column just left of me`. If we use `COUNT()` to count all the cells that have a numeric value, it'll ignore the first two columns of text and count all the number cells in that range. Adding one at the end lets you count up,

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this but I've just realized the document also contains other numbers.

Comment: Could you formula be adapted for use in this situation?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1594972/excel-change-cell-value-to-fist-left-value-plus-current-value

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to use find and replace for values other than just one. If it's a small number of other values, just do it manually. If it is a lot of other values, you can use VBA to automate the find and replace operation.

Comment: I just chucked it all into python then exported it out